# What are the rules for "Level Up" cards?

Tags: megaman-nt-warrior-tcg

There are 5 cards that require you to spend some number of "Level Up" cards in order to play them. (DarkCannon, All About Endurance, Double Power, Infamous Dr. Wily, and Pink Pixel Brat)

The "Level Up" cards themselves come in 3 types - MegaMan, GutsMan, and Roll.

All of these cards were only distributed through tournament participation rather than through the regular card sets. Perhaps for this reason, I did not see any mention of these "Level Up" cards in the rulebooks, so I do not know how they are meant to be played. The Level Up cards have no text on them to explain how to get them into play.

I am looking for a complete explanation of the rules for these cards. This would include any deck building restrictions, when and how the Level Up card comes into play, and what happens when it is spent for another card's effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Level Up!" cards themselves do not go in your deck and do not count toward the 60-card size of your deck. You begin the game with your "Level Up!" cards in a pile to the side of your play area.

The three "Level Up!" cards (MegaMan, GutsMan, and Roll) are functionally identical. They are not restricted to use only by decks of the pictured character.

To spend a "Level Up!" card, you move it to a separate pile. The spent "Level Up!" card cannot be used again for the rest of the game.

You can start the game with as many "Level Up!" cards as you want.

In tournament play, the number of "Level Up!" cards you could use was restricted by "the level indicated on your tournament ticket". As the "Level Up!" cards were given out based on "experience points" gained by tournament participation, I believe the restriction based on "your tournament ticket" meant you were only allowed to use as many "Level Up!" cards as you had personally received as prizes through the Level Up tournament program.

The information contained in this answer comes from the article [Level Up Your Game and Earn Exclusive Cards!](https://web.archive.org/web/20060106084601/http://megamantcg.fanhq.com:80/Articles/Article.aspx?ID=338) by Dan Bojanowski, Manager of Organized Play.

> Beginning July 2nd, gamers everywhere will get the chance to play Decipher's newest trading card game – MegaMan TCG. The gameplay and fast-paced action will be enough to draw players in, but we're taking it one step further with the organized play program.
>
> Similar to Decipher's .hack//ENEMY TCG, MegaMan TCG tournament players will be able to 'Level Up.' Every time a player participates in a sanctioned MegaMan TCG tournament, they will earn Experience Points. These Experience Points will reflect both a players' skill and participation in tournaments. When your ranking reaches 1,000 points, you will receive an email with a special code from Decipher. When this code is entered on the Decipher website, you will receive a special Level Up! package. Each package includes a foil Level Up! card and a special foil promo card. Each time your ranking increases by another 1,000 points, you will receive a code for a new prize package.
>
> The Level Up! card you receive is randomly selected from a pool of three different versions, each featuring a different character: MegaMan, Gutsman, or Roll. The only difference between versions is the character featured; there is no difference in gameplay.
>
> The Level Up! card is a special card that doesn't count toward your 60-card deck. You can bring as many Level Up! cards to the game as you want, up to the level indicated on your tournament ticket. Before the game begins, place your Level Up! cards to one side of your play area. Level Up! cards are used to play the special promo cards.
>
> The special promo card you receive is randomly selected from a pool of five different cards. The promo plays like a regular event or BattleChip card and follows regular deck construction rules (no more than four of any one promo card in your deck). These cards are exclusive to the organized play system. Click on the thumbnail to see Double Power, one of the tournament promo cards you can earn every time you Level Up! (The other tournament promos can be seen on the Tournament Card List.)
>
> To play a promo card, you'll have to "spend" (remove from play) one or more of your Level Up! cards. Place cards you have removed from play off to the side in a separate pile. You can't use those cards in that game again, but they'll be available again when you start your next game.